# Speech Recognition in Tkinter not responding after click on button

Tags: python, tkinter, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

i'm working on application which convert speech input to mathematical symbols. i'm using Tkinter + Speech Recognitio API
here is my speech recognition function :

```
def speech():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        audio = r.listen(source,timeout=5)


        try:
            speech = r.recognize_google(audio)
            
            wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()
            SUP = {ord(c): ord(t) for c, t in zip(u"0123456789xy+", u"⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹ˣʸ⁺")}

            def power():
                both = filtered_sentence
                both = [" ".join([wnl.lemmatize(word) for word in sentence.split(" ")]) for sentence in both]
                
                optr=[]
                for op in both:
                    si = op.replace('plus','+').replace('add','+').replace('multiply','x').replace('into','x').replace('minus','-').replace('squared','\u00b2').replace('Square','\u00b2').replace('square','\u00b2').replace('equal','=').replace('equals','=').replace('cube','\u00b3').replace('+','+').replace('-','-').replace('zero','0').replace('one','1').replace('two','2').replace('three','3').replace('four','4').replace('five','5').replace('six','6').replace('seven','7').replace('eight','8').replace('nine','9')
                    #print(si)
                    optr.append(si)
                
                power=[]
                for n,i in enumerate(optr):
                    if i == 'power' or i == 'raise':
                        power.append(n)
                        optr[n] = ''
                print(power)
                print(optr)
                for x in power:
                    for n,i in enumerate(optr[x:]):
                        if i == 'stop':
                            optr[n+x] = ''
                            break
                        for j in range(x+1,n+x+1):
                            optr[j] = optr[j].translate(SUP)    
                # print(filtered_sentence)
                #print('only power')
                print(optr)
                # print(PowBrack)
                eq = ''.join(optr)
                print(eq)
                text_editor.insert(tk.END,eq)

            def bracket():
                both = filtered_sentence
                both = [" ".join([wnl.lemmatize(word) for word in sentence.split(" ")]) for sentence in both]
                
                optr=[]
                for x in both:
                    si = x.replace('plus','+').replace('add','+').replace('multiply','x').replace('into','x').replace('minus','-').replace('squared','\u00b2').replace('Square','\u00b2').replace('square','\u00b2').replace('equal','=').replace('equals','=').replace('cube','\u00b3').replace('+','+').replace('-','-').replace('vi','6').replace('zero','0').replace('one','1').replace('two','2').replace('three','3').replace('four','4').replace('five','5').replace('six','6').replace('seven','7').replace('eight','8').replace('nine','9')
                    #print(si)
                    optr.append(si)
                
                
                bracket=[]
                for n,i in enumerate(optr):
                    if i == "bracket":
                        bracket.append(n)
                        optr[n] = "("
                print(optr)
                for x in bracket:
                    for n,i in enumerate(optr[x:]):
                        if i == "stop":
                            optr[n+x] = ")"
                # print('only Bracket')
                print(optr)
                # print(PowBrack)
                eq = ''.join(optr)
                print(eq)
                text_editor.insert(tk.END,eq)
                            
            def bracketPower():
                both = filtered_sentence
                both = [" ".join([wnl.lemmatize(word) for word in sentence.split(" ")]) for sentence in both]
                
                optr=[]
                for op in both:
                    si = op.replace('plus','+').replace('add','+').replace('multiply','x').replace('into','x').replace('minus','-').replace('squared','\u00b2').replace('Square','\u00b2').replace('square','\u00b2').replace('equal','=').replace('equals','=').replace('cube','\u00b3').replace('+','+').replace('-','-').replace('zero','0').replace('one','1').replace('two','2').replace('three','3').replace('four','4').replace('five','5').replace('six','6').replace('seven','7').replace('eight','8').replace('nine','9')
                    #print(si)
                    optr.append(si)
                
                PowBrack = []
                for n,i in enumerate(optr):
                    if i == 'bracket':
                        optr[n] = '('
                    elif i == "stop":
                        optr[n] = ")"
                    elif i == 'power' or i == 'raise':
                        optr[n] = ''
                        PowBrack.append(n)
                for x in PowBrack:
                    for n,i in enumerate(optr[x:]):
                        if i == ')':
                            optr[n+x] = ''
                            break
                        for j in range(x+1,n+x+1):               
                            optr[j] = optr[j].translate(SUP)
                print(optr)
                # print(PowBrack)
                eq = ''.join(optr)
                print(eq)
                text_editor.insert(tk.END,eq)        

            stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))

            word_data = speech
            word_data = word_data.lower()
            print(word_data)
            wnltk_tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(word_data)

            stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english')) 
            stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english')) - set(['y', 'a','d','into'])
            word_tokens =  wnltk_tokens

            filtered_sentence = [w for w in word_tokens if not w in stop_words]  

            filtered_sentence = []  
            for w in word_tokens:  
                if w not in stop_words:  
                    filtered_sentence.append(w)  

            # print(word_tokens)  
            for n,i in enumerate(filtered_sentence):
                if i == "(":
                    filtered_sentence[n] = "bracket"
                if i == ")":
                    filtered_sentence[n] = "bracket"
            
            print(filtered_sentence)

            if 'raise' in filtered_sentence and not 'bracket' in filtered_sentence or 'power' in filtered_sentence and not 'bracket' in filtered_sentence:
                power()
            elif 'bracket' in  filtered_sentence and not 'raise' in filtered_sentence and not 'power' in filtered_sentence:
                bracket()
            elif 'bracket' and 'power' or 'raise' in filtered_sentence:
                bracketPower()
            else:
                filtered_sentence = [" ".join([wnl.lemmatize(word) for word in sentence.split(" ")]) for sentence in filtered_sentence]
                
                optr=[]
                for op in filtered_sentence:
                    si = op.replace('plus','+').replace('add','+').replace('multiply','x').replace('into','x').replace('minus','-').replace('squared','\u00b2').replace('Square','\u00b2').replace('square','\u00b2').replace('equal','=').replace('equals','=').replace('cube','\u00b3').replace('+','+').replace('-','-').replace('zero','0').replace('one','1').replace('two','2').replace('three','3').replace('four','4').replace('five','5').replace('six','6').replace('seven','7').replace('eight','8').replace('nine','9')
                    #print(si)
                    optr.append(si)
                
                eq = ''.join(optr)
                print(eq)
                text_editor.insert(tk.END,eq)
                  
            # power = []


            # print(documents)


            # print(optr)

            
                
            
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error: " + str(e))
```

here is tkinter button code

```
speech_icon = tk.PhotoImage(file = "icon/function.png")
speech_button=Button(tool_bar_label,image=speech_icon,bd=0,command=speech,activebackground = '#c1bfbf')
speech_button.grid(row=0,column=11,padx=5,pady=5)
```

1. when i click on button, speech function call after that my
   application take input and also convert  into text and mathematical
   symbol but during this process my application going to **Not
   Responding**.And also it will keeps on taking the input until the
   microphone is disable.
2. I want it to take input until i speak. After that it should stop taking input.

Comment: Please focus your post around one question only.

Comment: Have you tried using threading?

Comment: no i don't know how to implement that but thank you for answering i will find that and if you have any links related to threading then it hepls me alot Thank You

Comment: Try `import threading` then change `command=lambda: threading.Thread(target=speech).start()`.

Comment: yes i found the same code but still my application going to **Not Responding**.

Comment: I am out of ideas :(

Comment: Thank you for your efforts :)